# Trying to rename a column in R but i am getting an error

Tags: r

I am trying to rename a column with dplyr but i am geting an error saying "Error in `chr_as_locations()`: ! Can't rename columns that don't exist." meanwhile the column exists

This is the code

```
total_home_goals <- total_home_goals %>% 
  rename(team = total_home_goals$`epl_21_22$HomeTeam`)
```

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that both plyr and dplyr provide a rename function.

Because we loaded the dplyr package last, the R programming language tries to use the dplyr package’s rename function.

You can use the plyr function to answer the question this way

```
total_home_goals <- plyr::rename(total_home_goals, c("epl_21_22$HomeTeam"= "team" , "epl_21_22$fulltime_home_goals" = "home_goals") )
```